# Python: Nested dictionaries: getting string(key+value) as values then swap with keys, combining dictionaries

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Say I have this 3 dictionaries:

```
d1 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'}, 'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
d2 = {'Ben': {'Strength': 'wo_mana', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Speed': 'wo_mana'}, 'Tom': {'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Agility': 'wo_mana'}}
d3 = {'Ben': {'Strength': '1.10', 'Int': '1.20', 'Speed': '1.50'}, 'Tom': {'Int': '1.40', 'Agility': '1.60'}}
```

I want to get something like this:

```
d123_new = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10', 'Speed = 1.50'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'},
'Tom': {'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.40'], 'wo_mana': ['Agility = 1.60'], 'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
```

which I think it is easier (I could be wrong) for me to print in a table format like this:

```
Name Skill Magic wo_mana          wi_mana
Ben  true  false Strength = 1.10  Int = 1.20
                 Speed = 1.50
Tom  true  true  Agility = 1.60   Int = 1.40
```

So I think I have to combine/append the `d1` and `d2` first, and this is my code and result (`d12`) for this part:

```
import itertools, collections

def update(d, u):
    for k, v in u.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, collections.Mapping):
            r = update(d.get(k, {}), v)
            d[k] = r
        else:
            d[k] = u[k]
    return d
d12 = update(d2, d1)
print(d12)

d12 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false', 'Strength': 'wo_mana', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Speed': 'wo_mana'},
       'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Agility': 'wo_mana'}}
```

Then, I want to get `d3_new` which is something like this:

```
d3_new = {'Ben': ['Strength = 1.10', 'Int = 1.20', 'Speed = 1.50'],
          'Tom': ['Int = 1.40', 'Agility = 1.60']}
```

my code and result(`d3_new`) for this part:

```
d3_new = {}
for i in d3;
    a = ''.join(['%s = %s' %(k,v) for k,v in d3[i].iteritems()])
    d3_new[i] = list()
    d3_new[i].append(a)
print(d3_new)

d3_new = {'Ben': ['Int = 1.20Strength = 1.10Speed = 1.50'],
          'Tom': ['Int = 1.40Agility = 1.60']}
```

Obviously, my desired output and the output that I get for `d3_new` is different. How should I fix this?

What is my next step after I got the desired output for `d3_new`? Or should I follow these steps in the first place:

a) change `d3` to `d3_new`

b) merge `d2` and `d3_new` to

```
d23 = {'Ben': {'wo_mana': ['Strength = 1.10', 'Speed = 1.50'], 'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.20']},
       'Tom': {'wi_mana': ['Int = 1.40'], 'wo_mana': ['Agility = 1.60']}}
```

c) combine `d1` and `d23` using the append method I did for `d12`

How should I do for `b)`?

Please advice me if `d123_new` is not suitable to print the data in my desired table format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could do the trick:

```
d4 = {}
for k, v in d2.items():
  d4[k] = {}
  for k2, v2 in v.items():
    try:
      if v2 not in d4[k]:
        d4[k][v2] = [k2 + ' = ' + d3[k][k2]]
      else:
        d4[k][v2].append(k2 + ' = ' + d3[k][k2])
    except KeyError:
        # this means k2 is a typo in d2; skip
        assert k in d3 # be sure that a missing name isn't causing the KeyError
        # you only need to use pass when you don't have any other operations in the scope

for k, v in d1.items():
  for k2, v2 in v.items():
    d4[k][k2] = v2

print(d4 == d123_new)
# -> True
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please share some tips to me on how you come out with this trick? How am I supposed to think of a way like this?

Comment: No problem! As you work your way through your d2 dict you can populate a new dict (d4 here) using the nested value as the new nested key and the nested key + the value in d3 associated with that key as the new nested value. Then you just add in the values from d1 and you're good to go. Clear as mud, right? ;)

Comment: Do you know why I got a KeyError when executing this line `d4[k][v2].append(k2 + ' = ' + d3[k][k2])` ?

Comment: Hmm... You might be missing a value in d3 somewhere if your inputs are bigger than in the example. You can try swapping out d3[k][k2] with d3.get(k, {}).get(k2, None) or you can wrap it in a try: / except: block to handle KeyErrors more generally.

Comment: So it may be due to the value is missing in the input file?   Can you please show me how to wrap it in a `try :/ except: block`? I will try with `d3.get(k, {}).get(k2, None)` for now.

Comment: Is there a way to fix this besides going through 2000 pages to find the missing value? can we do like append the value as usual, if got keyerror, then append/set a default key/value or something like that?

Comment: or can I find the difference of `d2` and `d3` to see what nested keys(`strength`, `agility`, `speed` etc) are missing in `d3`?

Comment: Alright, I have found out the cause of this problem. There is a key missing in `d3` but it exist in `d2`. This is because of typo in the input file. Suppose that I could not modify the file, what should I do to handle this extra key which should not exist in the first place?

Comment: Ok, I've edited the answer to handle the typos in d2. Be aware that it could potentially miss real keys, so you might want to run an assertion or two in the except: block to make sure that it is indeed a typo.

Comment: Thank you for your time and patience, I will test it after I wake up in the morning the next day, but can I ask you what do you mean by potentially missing real keys and 'run an assertion or two in the except: block'? could you please show me an example?

Comment: Another question by using your code, if `KeyError` is detected, then execute `pass` meaning that the key+value will not be appended, am I right? What is the better way or usual way to handle this besides `pass`?

Comment: I made that edit; assert will raise an AssertionError if d3 is actually missing a consequential key (a name) but will just ignore the KeyError otherwise. The pass statement is just a placeholder.

Comment: Ok, so if the `name` is in `d2` and `d3` but the nested key, for example, if `strength` is in `d2` but missing in `d3` for `Ben` only, what will happen to `strength` when executing `d4[k][v2] = [k2 + ' = ' + d3[k][k2]]` or `d4[k][v2].append(k2 + ' = ' + d3[k][k2])` ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can do this:

```
d1 = {'Ben': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'false'}, 
      'Tom': {'Skill': 'true', 'Magic': 'true'}}
d2 = {'Ben': {'Strength': 'wo_mana', 'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Speed': 'wo_mana'},   
      'Tom': {'Int': 'wi_mana', 'Agility': 'wo_mana'}}
d3 = {'Ben': {'Strength': '1.10', 'Int': '1.20', 'Speed': '1.50'}, 
      'Tom': {'Int': '1.40', 'Agility': '1.60'}}

d123_new = {} # create an empty dict

for key in d1: # run over first dict and get the keys containing names

    try:   # Case of Skill

        d = {
             key:{ # we know the key and Agility case 
                  d2[key]['Agility']:['Agility='+d3[key]['Agility']],
                  d2[key]['Int']: ['Int='+d3[key]['Agility']],
                  'Skill':d1[key]['Skill'],'Magic':d1[key]['Magic']
             }
       }

   except KeyError: # case of Strength

       d = {
             key:{ # no Agility - Strength
                  d2[key]['Strength']:['Strength='+d3[key]['Strength'],
                  'Speed='+d3[key]['Speed']],
                  d2[key]['Int']: ['Int='+d3[key]['Strength']],
                 'Skill':d1[key]['Skill'],'Magic':d1[key]['Magic']
             }
        }

    d123_new.update(d)

print d123_new # output the result
```

Comment: looks complicated to me, what is the name of this method?

Comment: You know the first key in all dictionaries is First Name, than you know that for the nested dictionary under First Name (Ben or Tom or whoever) it's either Strength or  Agility - if one fails another one succeeds, once you know this you know which parameters to substitute from  d1,d2 and d3 as the data is there, you just need to know if its Agility or Strength, so it's not really complicated. but does not require a nested loop.